# PHP form required fields

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that will be loaded into a div on another page through AJAX. On click, I would like to check required fields for content. If required fields are not populated, I want to put a message next to the field like in this example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp.

If name were required for example, here I would like to add

```
 if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
  else
    {$name=$_POST['name'];}
```

On Submit:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
// Connect to DB 
XXX

$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
implode(',',$_POST['check']);
 //or something like
$checkstring="";
foreach($_POST['check'] as $checkboxes) {
  $checkstring.= $checkboxes .",";
}
$c = rtrim($checkstring);

$query = "INSERT INTO contact VALUES ('$name','$phone', '$c', '$category')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
echo "Hi! $name. Your phone number <b> $phone </b> is in our database";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And here I would add

```
<?php echo $nameErr;?>
```

next to the name field. 
But when I put

```
?>
```

in the php variable, it breaks up the variable because it thinks I am ending the

```
<?php
```

at the top of Form.

Form:

```
<?php  

// Get value of clicked button 
$button = $_GET['button']; 

$test = '<center>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 20px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>Demo</h1>
<form id="ContactForm" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
<div class="form_result"> </div> 

    Name: <input name="name" type=text ><br>

    Phone: <input name="phone" type=text ><br>

    Business Capabilities:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="c1">C1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="c2">C2<br>

    <select name="category">Category:
        <option value="d1">D1</option>
        <option value="d2">D2</option>
        <option value="d3">D3</option>
    </select><br>

<input type="submit" >
</form>
</center>
'; 

print json_encode($test);

?>
```

Is it possible for me to put that php statement in the php variable? Or is there another way that would be cleaner to do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please use the `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` class instead of the deprecated `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `echo` it.  You're creating a giant HTML string, just use string concatenation to include your error:

```
$test = 'blah blah blah '.$nameErr.' blah blah blah';
```

Before you go any further though, stop and learn about prepared statements - what you're currently doing with your database is very dangerous, and highly susceptible to sql injection attacks.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Hi Madbreaks, using the string concatenation did not work for me. After doing that, the form would not load into the div. As for learning about prepared statements, I know mysql is deprecated but I just wanted to make a quick mockup of something using what I knew. I will look into that soon! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a long night, I don't have the complete effort to use your code (so I apologize).  But I should be able to get you on the right track.  I suggest using JSON as a response in your `submit.php` page that is called by AJAX.  So for example, your script could have:

```
if(empty($_POST["name"])) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => 'Name is required.'
    ));
} else {
    // Do form stuff here

    echo json_encode(array(
        'phone' => $phone
    ));
}
```

Then in your AJAX call, you can easily handle your JSON (in a more modular way, allowing you to easily change your responses/layout).

```
$.ajax('submit.php', {
    // Settings
    dataType: 'json' // We want JSON response, this will parse it as an object
}).done(function(data) {
    if(data.error !== 'undefined') {
        alert('Error: ' + data.error);
    } else {
        alert('Your phone number is ' + data.phone);
    }
});
```

Feel free to ask if you need more explanation on what I am doing here.